# React HTML5 Video controls

Tags: html, reactjs, video, webcam, video-recording

so I am trying to create a webcam type functionality where users can click record right in the browser and then record a video and then either download or upload it.

It is modelled on the site at https://www.tellamericaitsgreat.com/

So far I have code that will use the webcam and show the video as HTML5 video on the screen but it doesn't record (it just plays and pauses on the screen) or download/upload.

This has to be done in React. I am trying to use https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC

My code right now for the video is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Record.css';

class Record extends Component {
  render() {
    var RecordRTC = require('recordrtc');
        function successCallback(stream){
      var vid = document.querySelector('video');
      vid.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
      vid.muted = true;
      var recorder = RecordRTC(stream, {
         type: 'video'
      });
      recorder.startRecording();

      setTimeout(function(){
      recorder.stopRecording(function(){
           var blob = recorder.blob;
           var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
           vid.src = url;
           vid.muted = false;
      });
      }, 5 * 1000);
    }

    function errorCallback(error){
      alert(error);
    }


    var mediaConstraints = {video: true, audio: true};

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints).then(successCallback).catch(errorCallback);

    return (
      <video controls autoplay id="video"></video>
    );
  }
}

export default Record;
```

Comment: is there a question you have with this? You aren't giving us much clarity into what issue you have.

Comment: Sorry, my question is that I cannot get the record and download/upload functionality to work.

It works in the example on the website but I don't know how to use it in React

Comment: @Dreamer Please check these links: [https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC#frameworks](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC#frameworks)

Comment: @MuazKhan I have read that link and it is not really helpful. I just want a really simple implementation where the component has buttons for recording, pausing and downloading the file. That's it. 

The example file has too much other stuff and I can't figure it out :(